# Alternative ways to say "I am feeling pushed to the ground"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, idioms

Assume a get together where a group of friends are having chit chat over tea. Suddenly they plan to pull someone's leg together. No matter what the person in the spotlight says, people are not supporting him and teasing him playfully or in malice. This is the point where the person can use the above statement which means nobody is supporting him. Is there any other way (s)he could say it? I need both the formal and informal ways preferably with a humorous yet firm connotation.

**Edit 1:** I need an expression which would provide an indication to others to let you go/cut you some slack in a very friendly way like the above the expression does.

Comment: Are you in the US or in the UK? This makes a difference to a slang expression which fits perfectly for this type of situation.

Comment: In BrEng it would be ["Stop taking the piss out of (me)"](http://thetab.com/uk/oxford/2015/01/22/stop-taking-piss-accent-21099)

Comment: I am non-native speaker.  So both US or UK would do.

Answer (score 2):

You could say *he was the **[butt of the joke](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/butt+of+a+joke)***

> the reason for or aim of a joke, especially when it is a person. *Poor Fred was the butt of every joke told that evening.*

*McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs*

The origin of the phrase is discussed in [this ELU question and answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19949/origin-of-the-idiom-butt-of-jokes).

A more formal term might be *[taunt](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/taunt)*

> 1. to provoke or deride with mockery, contempt, or criticism
> 2. to tease; tantalize

You also could say *I don't enjoy the **[put downs](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-down_1)*** (or *being put down*)

> (informal) something that you say or do to criticize someone or make them appear foolish:
>
> *I see the term as a put-down of women.*
>
> *She was getting very sick of Mick's put-downs.*

*Collins English Dictionary*

Comment: That is what an observer would say. I need the statement to be made by the first person. It should be like something which is a cue for them to stop their taunts. I guess I should have added that in the question.

Comment: *Please stop taunting me* or *I'm tired of being the butt of the joke*.

Comment: Or you could say *Does nobody have my back?* (meaning, *is nobody standing up for me or protecting me?*).

Comment: The latest one sounds like a good emotional blackmail XD and perhaps better than the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

- "Please stop teasing me, you make me  feel like the [laughing stock](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+laughing+stock) of everyone".

> - someone who does something very stupid which makes other people laugh at them (usually + of ).  *I can't cycle around on that old thing! I'll be the laughing stock of the neighbourhood.*

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary)

Comment: Would this work if it's not necessary something stupid? Everybody wants to drive the person crazy simply because they enjoy it. It's like one person started annoying the person and everyone else is engaged in make-hay-while-the-sun-shine act.

Comment: I think that it may  fit the context, I understand that the person is treated (just for teasing him/her) as if she/he had done something stupid. The fact that everybody joins this to do this can be seen as a sort of 'bandwagon effect'.

Answer (score 1):

> You're ganging up on me!

Feeling *[ganged up on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gang+up+on)*, or some variation of it. When a group of people all join in, in opposition to a single person.

Comment: "You're ganging up on me!"

Comment: I am not familiar with this expression, but from the examples available it appears to have a stronger connotation than the one asked by OP: 
***to unite as a group against someone*** , *It seemed like my creditors were ganging up on me.*

Comment: Gang up:   ***to make a joint assault*** 1)  <ganged up on him and beat him up>

1) to combine for a specific purpose <ganged up to raise prices>
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gang%20up

Answer (score 1):

**"Okay, okay, uncle!"** (said by the person getting attacked).

To cry uncle: *Concede defeat, as in The Serbs want the Bosnians to cry uncle,* Farlex Dictionary of Idioms

The phrase I've proposed is a bit sarcastic.  It's an amusing way of showing that the person was being quite aggressive.

---

If you think your teasers won't be familiar with *cry uncle*, here's an alternative:

(Slapping both hands to clutch your chest dramatically, while falling, or almost falling, out of your chair) You got me!  Man down!

Answer (score 1):

My twelve-year-old and spouse contribute:

First, act out crying.  Then, holding the imaginary dagger sticking in your chest with one hand (elbow sticking out sideways), suddenly hitting your forehead with the back of your other hand histrionically, and leaning back like you've been hit, declaim à la Hamlet: "Before I die, I must tell everyone the sad story of my life and all my failings so that they may avoid dying an untimely death as I lie dying here -- I was born three minutes too early to be the first baby born in the new year in my town" and more boring imaginary details of your life story.

They say the key is the style of delivery.